# Test and Enable CRM Mailbox programmatically

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there a way to "Test and Enable" CRM Mailbox programmatically either using Powershell or CRM SDK? This is for initial user setup.

I have tried using Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell, it does have Approve-CrmEmailAddress and Set-CrmUserMailbox but there doesn't seem to be a way to Enable Mailbox.

Comment: What do you need to accomplish? Is it for using a test email address where you can just test if an email was sent to somebody or what?

Comment: We are provisioning hundreds of new CRM users and one of the step is to click "Approve Email" button followed by "Test and Enable MAILBOXES" button. I am trying to automate the user creation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afr - have you made any progress or found anything out with this? I am currently looking into the same thing. For some reason the mailboxes for a client of mine are being deactivated and upon reactivate I need to test & enable. But since the mailboxes that are deactivated are random - doing something dynamic in c# is a much better way to go.

Comment: Afr - I have an update, there is a field named testemailconfigurationscheduled on the mailbox entity. If you set that to true - it will trigger the test and enable logic. Give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

Afr thanks for trying out the Xrm Data Powershell module - I noticed that we haven't added that functionality yet so I'll work to get it checked in for the 2.6 release. As long as your mailbox has something to be enabled for (Incoming/Outgoing/ACT) then you can set the testemailconfigurationscheduled to true and check the result after it runs the test/enable process in the background.  There also is a way to postpone/schedule it, but most folks want it run right away when they execute the request. You can also set the orgmarkedasprimaryforexchangesync, this tells the enable process to stamp the users mailbox so any other CRM environments know they no longer can sync with the users mailbox (only one org can sync to a mailbox at any one time).

HTH!
Sean